# How to fix the git filter error of not changing the edits to the master?

Tags: git, github, git-filter-branch, git-filter

i am trying to change the timestamp of a local commit using git filter, but i just get that error and no changes to the commits made.
Is there anyway to change the timestamp of a commit rather than this or fix the error appeared after the command?

```
ia@a:~/Desktop/testGit$ git filter-branch --env-filter \
'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = b1d63c62a3a1139a18cf0349980db9f2df331ff2]
 then 
  export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE= "Sun Mar 4 12:12:19 2018 +0200"
  export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Sat May 19 01:01:01 2007 -0700"
```

The error:

```
fi' Rewrite b1d63c62a3a1139a18cf0349980db9f2df331ff2 (1/2) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)   
/usr/lib/git-core/git-filter-branch: 1: [: missing ] Rewrite
f4c6559bcc18b496f8b258a0a7d142d8bee323b8 (2/2) (0 seconds passed,
remaining 0 predicted)    /usr/lib/git-core/git-filter-branch: 1: [:
missing ]

WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
```

Comment: `if [ $GIT_COMMIT = b1d63c62a3a1139a18cf0349980db9f2df331ff2"a space is needed here"]`. It should be `if [ $GIT_COMMIT = b1d63c62a3a1139a18cf0349980db9f2df331ff2 ]`

Comment: If you want to rewrite just one commit why not use `rebase`?

Comment: @ElpieKay i corrected it and the response is Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten ,but after hitting git log the date of the commit still sun mar 4 not sat may 19

Comment: @phd How to use rebase to change the date of a commit before pushing to gitgub?

Comment: `git log` shows the author date by default. If you'd like to see the commit date, check it with `git log --pretty=%cd`.

Comment: @ElpieKay so, i think i need to change the author data, too. i want to push the commits to github and i need it to appear in all the ways to be made a week ago. is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

To edit just one commit use [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode). Run

```
git rebase --interactive b1d63c62a3a1139a18cf0349980db9f2df331ff2~
```

(note the tilde!) In the opened editor verify that the first commit is b1d63c6 and edit its command in the first column — replace `pick` with `edit`. Save the todo file and exit the editor. `git rebase` stops at the first commit.

Edit the commit:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Sun Mar 4 12:12:19 2018 +0200" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Sat May 19 01:01:01 2007 -0700" git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Continue rebasing:

```
git rebase --continue
```

Wait until git finishes and verify the result:

```
git show --format=fuller $NEW_SHA1_FOR_REBASED_COMMIT
```

(A news sha1 ID is required because `rebase` changes commit IDs).

Comment: there is some errors doing this: fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream 069e4a5517882cad1a824da220894e36f696e7e1~

Comment: At what command? What is the commit 069e4a5517882cad1a824da220894e36f696e7e1?

Comment: after git rebase --interactive 069e4a5517882cad1a824da220894e36f696e7e1~ it took another SHA after the previous edits. It's my first commit in the current history

Comment: Let's me check: 069e4a5 is the first commit in the branch and b1d63c6 is the second one? Or the other way around?

Comment: Thanks for your patience: $ `git log
commit c23b4fd96f1fad7b3b72ee44724eb9595e582ab7
Author: i <i.ha@mc.com>
Date:   Sun Mar 4 12:36:42 2018 +0200
    adding adel

commit 069e4a5517882cad1a824da220894e36f696e7e1
Author: i <i.ha@mc.com>
Date:   Sun Mar 4 12:12:19 2018 +0200
    adding alex`  Those are my two and the only two commits now in the history

Comment: i just need to change everthing needed so after pushing them to github, there should appear as i made them a week ago

Comment: I see. 069e4a5 is the first and c23b4fd is the rebased second. Now you you need to finish rebase with `git rebase --continue`.